# How to get column values comma seperatedly

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get column values comma seperatedly in SQL Server. Below shown is my sql query#

```
 select BandName from BandMaster where BandId<100
```

I need to get the BandName values comma seperatedly in a single query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a list of T-SQL results with comma's between them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726660/how-to-make-a-list-of-t-sql-results-with-commas-between-them)

Comment: Any particular version of SQL Server?

Comment: Also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231439/need-faster-concat-of-columns-in-sql-server-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use XML path for this.

select (select BandName+',' from BandMaster where BandId<100 for xml path('')) as NewColumnName

Try this
```

Comment: It will return in XML format not in comma seprated.

Comment: It will return comma seperated itself. Pls try out, and then comment

Comment: Yes friend, I have tried out & then commented.It is comminig like this <BandName>A</BandName><BandName>B</BandName>. Am i missing on something?

Comment: No my frined, I know you haven't tried :).If you gave like this '**select BandName from BandMaster where BandId<100 for xml path('')'**, then it would be coming in the way you specified, I have specified a **select** in the outer query , to by pass the xml tags.Please try out

Comment: Is this correct? select (select status_name from status_master where isfollowup=4 for xml path('')) as NewColumnName

Comment: **select (select status_name+',' from status_master where isfollowup=4 for xml path('')) as NewColumnName**..Please try out

Comment: Ya, now it working! So you that means you provided solution without Testing. Isn't it?Still Good solution!

Comment: T just wrote the query and checked whether result is coming.Didnt cross check the resut.My mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT BandName  = 
              STUFF ( ( SELECT ','+InrTab.BandName 
                        FROM [Table1] InrTab
                        WHERE InrTab.BandId= OutTab.BandId
                                            AND InrTab.BandId < 100                     
                        ORDER BY InrTab.BandId
                        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE 
                       ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                      , 1,1,SPACE(0))
FROM [Table1] OutTab
GROUP BY OutTab.BandId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(BandName) from BandMaster where BandId<100`.

Comment: No GROUP_CONCAT in SQL SEREVR

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @retStr varchar(max) = ''
select @retStr = @retStr + BandName + ',' from BandMaster
where BandId<100 

Select @retStr
```